# VBA: case insentitive, if cell = string

Tags: vba, excel, macros

In this example, I'm wanting to remove the end of a string if it contains either bk, BK, Bk or bK. Is there a simple way to make this case insentitive? Thanks

```
If Right(Cells(i, 1), 2) = "bk" Then
    Cells(i, 1) = Replace(Cells(i, 1), "bk", "")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove only the last two characters, I suggest:

```
If UCase(R) Like "*bk" Then R = Left(R, Len(R) - 2)
```

where R is a range object (or text string)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since you want to replace all sorts of "bk" at the end of the string, you can use `UCase`, like in the code below:

```
If UCase(Right(Cells(i, 1), 2)) = "BK" Then
    Cells(i, 1) = Replace(Cells(i, 1), "bk", "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
End If
```

**Note**: adding the last parameter of `vbTextCompare` to the `Replace` function indicates that it's case-insensitive, and will remove all sorts of "bk".

**Edit 1**:
In case you have multiple occurrences of "bk" in a certain string, and you only want to remove the one at the end of the string, use the code below (thanks to @Ron Rosenfeld):

```
If UCase(Right(Cells(i, 1), 2)) = "BK" Then
    Cells(i, 1) = Left(Cells(i, 1), Len(Cells(i, 1)) - 2)
End If
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: @ShaiRado Your code will remove **ALL** of the `bk`'s in the string and not just the one at the end.